# Highchart | Piechart | Drilldown | Color

Tags: highcharts

I'm using Highchart 3.0.10. I'm setting my colors with the following code:

```
Highcharts.getOptions().colors = Highcharts.map(Highcharts.getOptions().colors,   
                function(color) {
            return {
                radialGradient: { cx: 0.5, cy: 0.3, r: 0.7 },
                stops: [
                    [0, color],
                    [1, Highcharts.Color(color).brighten(-0.3).get('rgb')] // darken
                ]
            };
        });
```

This works fine for the first call. After drilldown I have to move the mousepointer over the chart to see some colors. Comming back always one color is lost and replaced by grey. Any ideas?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Probably bug in 3.0.10, try to use master branch: `http://http://github.highcharts.com/highcharts.src.js`. If this won't help, recreate issue on jsFiddle.

Comment: Hmmm, seems to be that the following piece of code throws an Uncaught TypeError: Property 'select' of object #<Object> is not a function                                                  if (eventType === 'click' && seriesOptions.allowPointSelect) {
   defaultFunction = function (event) {
    // Control key is for Windows, meta (= Cmd key) for Mac, Shift for Opera
    point.select(null, event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey || event.shiftKey);
   };
  }

Comment: master branch behaves the same way.

Comment: Without live demo it's hard to guess. See master example: http://jsfiddle.net/HnE9v/